# How can I get the complement in this SQL query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a bigquery database that has some latitude and longitude. Over this database, I run a query using CTE and the `ST_COVERS` bigquery function. The total sub-set is 518 rows and the points that apply to the CTE chain are 423. How can I get the remaining rows? I have tried to join, union all, left join, inner join, and other stuff, but I can't get the total 518 rows.

PD: I'm not posting the query because it's quite long (probably can be optimized a lot), but I can post it if it is really needed.

EDIT: This is the query (or most important parts of it). With this query, I can get all `lat,lon` points that are within some polygons. What I'm looking for is also to get the `lat,lon` points that are outside of all polygons and assign them a tag "NA" in the `sector` column.

```
WITH staging AS(
  SELECT id,
         lat,
         lon
  FROM
       lat_lon_table),

 area_1 AS(
 SELECT id,
        lat,
        lon,
        "area_1" AS sector,
        ST_COVERS(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT("POLYGON((#some lat lon coordinates))"),
        ST_GEOPOINT(lat,lon)) as `covers`
 FROM
     staging),

 area_2 AS(
 SELECT id,
        lat,
        lon,
        "area_2" AS sector,
        ST_COVERS(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT("POLYGON((#other lat lon coordinates))"),
        ST_GEOPOINT(lat,lon)) as `covers`
 FROM
     staging),

 area_3 AS(
 SELECT id,
        lat,
        lon,
        "area_3" AS sector,
        ST_COVERS(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT("POLYGON((#other lat lon coordinates))"),
        ST_GEOPOINT(lat,lon)) as `covers`
 FROM
     staging),

 area_4 AS(
 SELECT id,
        lat,
        lon,
        "area_4" AS sector,
        ST_COVERS(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT("POLYGON((#other lat lon coordinates))"),
        ST_GEOPOINT(lat,lon)) as `covers`
 FROM
     staging),

 union_all AS(
 SELECT * FROM area_1
 UNION ALL(SELECT * FROM area_2)
 UNION ALL(SELECT * FROM area_3)
 UNION ALL(SELECT * FROM area_4))

 SELECT 
     id,
     lat,
     lon,
     sector
 FROM
     union_all
 WHERE
     covers = TRUE
```

Comment: Don't post the whole query - just essential part of it and clarify what is the expected result

Comment: Ok...I'll try to do my best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
#standardSQL
WITH staging AS(
  SELECT id, lat, lon FROM lat_lon_table
), area_1 AS(
  SELECT id, lat, lon, "area_1" AS sector,
    ST_COVERS(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT("POLYGON((#some lat lon coordinates))"), ST_GEOGPOINT(lat,lon)) as `covers`
  FROM staging
), area_2 AS (
  SELECT id, lat, lon, "area_2" AS sector,
    ST_COVERS(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT("POLYGON((#other lat lon coordinates))"), ST_GEOGPOINT(lat,lon)) as `covers`
  FROM staging
), area_3 AS (
  SELECT id, lat, lon, "area_3" AS sector,
    ST_COVERS(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT("POLYGON((#other lat lon coordinates))"), ST_GEOGPOINT(lat,lon)) as `covers`
  FROM staging
), area_4 AS (
  SELECT id, lat, lon, "area_4" AS sector,
    ST_COVERS(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT("POLYGON((#other lat lon coordinates))"), ST_GEOGPOINT(lat,lon)) as `covers`
  FROM staging
), union_all AS (
  SELECT * FROM area_1 UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM area_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM area_3 UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM area_4
)
SELECT id, lat, lon, sector FROM union_all 
WHERE covers = TRUE
UNION ALL
SELECT id, lat, lon, 'NA' FROM lat_lon_table 
WHERE NOT id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM union_all WHERE covers = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @Mikhail Berlyant! This worked :). Any suggestion on how I can also improve the query?

Comment: when I answered - I think I had something in mind but I was focusing on exact question and didn't  want to change anything in your initial query. Ok. I will check shortly and if have some idea(s) will post it as a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestion on how I can also improve the query?

Try below - it less verbose, easy to maintain and should be cheaper and faster (not tested)

```
#standardSQL
WITH staging AS(
  SELECT id, lat, lon FROM lat_lon_table
), areas AS(
  SELECT id, lat, lon, 
    IF(ST_COVERS(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT("POLYGON((#some  lat lon coordinates))"), ST_GEOGPOINT(lat,lon)), 'area_1', 'NA') AS area_1, 
    IF(ST_COVERS(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT("POLYGON((#other lat lon coordinates))"), ST_GEOGPOINT(lat,lon)), 'area 2', 'NA') AS area_2,
    IF(ST_COVERS(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT("POLYGON((#other lat lon coordinates))"), ST_GEOGPOINT(lat,lon)), 'area_3', 'NA') AS area_3,
    IF(ST_COVERS(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT("POLYGON((#other lat lon coordinates))"), ST_GEOGPOINT(lat,lon)), 'area_4', 'NA') AS area_4
  FROM staging
), union_all AS (
  SELECT id, lat, lon, 'area_1' AS sector FROM areas WHERE area_1 = 'area_1' UNION ALL
  SELECT id, lat, lon, 'area_2' FROM areas WHERE area_2 = 'area_2' UNION ALL
  SELECT id, lat, lon, 'area_3' FROM areas WHERE area_3 = 'area_3' UNION ALL
  SELECT id, lat, lon, 'area_4' FROM areas WHERE area_4 = 'area_4' UNION ALL
  SELECT id, lat, lon, 'NA' FROM areas WHERE (area_1, area_2, area_3, area_4) = ('NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA') 
)
SELECT * FROM union_all
```